# Intermittent "connection was aborted" error in Windows service connecting to MySql via EF

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm aware there a bunch of questions about this error already, but many of them don't have an answer, and I'm struggling to get a handle on how to troubleshoot it.

I have a Windows service which scans a drop folder for the presence of a file and springs into action when it finds one. From time to time - often, it seems, when it's been inactive for a while, it throws this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Here are the first few lines of code that are executed:

```
FileQueue fq = _rep.GetFile(file.FileId);
_log.Info(string.Format("Processing file {0} for job {1}", file.FileId, file.Job.Description));
SetJobToProcessing(file);
```

_rep is an instance of a repository class built on Entity Framework and connecting to MySql. The logger is NLog which writes to a log table in the same database. The instance is created when the windows service starts up. Here are are the relevant function definitions:

```
public void SetJobToProcessing(FileQueue file)
{
    file.Job.Status = JobStatus.Processing;
    _rep.Update(file);
    _rep.SaveChanges();
}
```

And from the repository:

```
public FileQueue GetFile(params object[] keyValues)
{
    return FileQueues.Find(keyValues);
}

public void Update<T>(T updateItem) where T : class
{
    Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(updateItem);
}

public int SaveChanges()
{
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

The error is intermittent but seems to occur when service hasn't had anything to do for a while. So I presumed this was some kind of timeout of keepalive issue.

But then I noticed that it's occurring on the call to `SetJobToProcessing`. That's the *third* call to the database in the sequence - the file is fetched first, then the action logged, and then it errors updating and saving data.

What can I do to solve or further investigate this issue? Should I be writing some sort of connection re-test function to try twice if it fails? Maybe creating and disposing of a repository object for each time the service polls the folder instead of on instantiation?

Comment: is it because you're not closing/opening DB connections and youre just getting the "I was bored so dropped you and now you tried to use it" error?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why you say that `SetJobToProcessing` is the third call to the database?  Do the calls to `_rep.GetFile()` or `_log.Info()` touch MySQL (it doesn't strike me that they do)?  In which case, isn't it perfectly reasonable that `SetJobToProcessing` would be the point of failure if MySQL has dropped the connection due to inactivity?

Comment: You may wish to tweak [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

Comment: @eggyal It's possible that `GetFile()` is pulling its data from memory, but the logger is inserting values into MySql.

Comment: Could it be that `_log` is using a different connection to `_rep`, which hasn't yet timed out?

Comment: @BugFinder I thought connection management was largely automatic in the latest version of EF?

Comment: @MattThrower I think it sort of is, however, we have an app here who gets the same kinds of messages and we've come to the conclusion that its because its opening a conneciton and then it gets bored rather than closing it, and sometimes they drop.. so raise an error when it should have dropped it due to non use

Comment: @BugFinder OK, thanks. I'll try increasing the timeout value and creating a ew rep each pass through the service, see if that helps.

Comment: If an increased `wait_timeout` is insufficient and spawning new repo instances on every invocation is too costly, you might consider first testing the liveness of the connection and only spawning a new repo instance if the connection has died (there might be some way to reuse the existing instance, e.g. by forcing a reconnect, but I'd have to dig through EF docs to find out how).

Comment: @eggyal Yes, thank you, that's what had in mind when I mentioned a "connection re-test function" in the question. Hopefully, it won't be too expensive to create one each time.

Comment: Reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849 ... it appears that EF should only keep the connections open for as long as the `DBContext` persists, unless you explicitly invoke `context.Database.Connection.Open()` yourself (in which case it keeps the connection open until closed manually).  Your `DBContext` should be created (and disposed) for each invocation of your script, whereas the repo should be able to persist over the service's lifetime.

Comment: @eggyal That's probably sufficient to make a worthwhile answer, if you want.